# Get stack trace for C# app crashing on non-dev machine

Tags: c#, debugging, clr, windbg

I have installed a C# windows forms app on a client machine which does not have Visual Studio installed.

When the application is run, it immediately crashes with a dialog which says

> ProgramX has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."

The only button on the dialog is "close the program".

I would like to see the exception message and stack trace so that I can diagnose the issue.

I have tried installing the .Net SDK, which comes with "windbg". I have run the program in windbg, and managed to get it to say "CLR exception". However, I cannot get windbg to print the exception message or stack trace. It will not load SOS or PSSCOR2, because of DLL loading messages, even after lots of fiddling. There must be an easier way!

(If your answer involves windbg, please include detailed step by step instructions as I have tried and failed at this approach.)

The application is a .Net 3.5 app. The machine has .Net 3.5 and .Net 4 installed. There is nothing in the event log (that I can find).

Comment: Write code that will capture all exceptions which is written to a log file.

Comment: do you have the power to change the source? windbg is a listener application - it echoes out debug statements from various sources. There's no black magic, and it can't conjure up output from thin air. However if you are able to modify the source code it is pretty trivial to modify your app to output debug messages.

Comment: @Pete: maybe you mean a different windbg? The one I have (came with the .Net SDK) is a fully featured (if rather obtuse) debugger, which can set breakpoints, inspect memory etc.. I just can't get it to print exceptions...

Comment: @Rich, sorry you're absolutely right. I was thinking of dbmon by mistake. I hate getting old!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you do NOT have access to source code** then you have a problem. Exceptions should finish in windows events. Maybe exception is being suppressed.

**If you DO have access to source code** you can surround starting code with TRY\CATCH and in CATCH and print exception info to a file:

- ex.message
- ex.InnerException.Message
- ex.StackTrace

Code

```
        try
        {
            //Your code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log info to a file in same directory
        }
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, thanks. I do have access to the source. I will add a catch around the code I suspect to be at fault, and add a global uncaught exception handler and recompile. We'll see if that catches it. (I suspect a DLL loading problem, which may be too low down for such handlers.)

Comment: As a general measure is always safe to surround main code with try/catch and log errors. If you are fancy you can use log4net.
If you don't have time at least log to a file. Be very careful with the code in catch to write to a file and make it defensive by creating file if it doesn't exist, append if it exists, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I added a global handler to write the exception to the event log, and I caught my index-out-of-bounds exception.

Answer (score 3):

- You can catch unhandled exceptions in one place in your code by adding a handler to the following event. You can then log or perform some other action.

  [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
- You can generate a crash dump from Task Manager (right-click on an entry in the `Processes` tab and select `Create Dump File`) and load it with WinDbg. Running the `!pe` command should display the exception. You will need the PDB files from your build and the correct version of the SOS DLL from the machine that crashed.

Comment: How can I generate a crash dump from Task Manager?

Comment: Right-click on an entry in the `Processes` tab and select `Create Dump File`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use ADPlus to take a crash dump of the app, and load the crash dump into WinDbg on your development machine:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/09/04/howto-generating-a-crash-dump-with-adplus.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350

You could also try setting up remote debugging (assuming you have the source code):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: That didn't work for me. I don't know why, but adplus didn't log any exceptions. I think it couldn't launch the app or something. I won't try again as cad's answer fixed this for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rich Sorry it didn't work out.  Something must have been catching that exception and then displaying that error dialog, and calling Exit.  If that is what was going on, the user sees a crash dialog, but windows sees an orderly shutdown, so ADPlus doesn't trigger.  Just my guess.